# How to display a text file within Safari that doesn't have the .txt extension?

Tags: macos, mac, html, safari

I have some html that hyperlinks to a text file that is on my desktop. However, this file uses a different file extension than .txt, and I don't want to change it. When I view the html file in Safari and click on the link, it opens Finder and shows me where the file is, because it doesn't realize it is just a text file. Is there some way to force Safari to display the file in the browser?

My HTML code looks like this: `<a href="myTextFile.qwert">Simple test file!</a>`

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on myTextfile.qwert.
2. Select *Get Info*
3. Go down to the *Open with:* section and select Safari there.